# Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter update - VM inaccessible

Tags: google-compute-engine

After updating windows with the optional update "**Red Hat, Inc. - LAN, LAN (Server) - Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter**" my VM restarted and became inaccessible!!!

If anyone has any idea on how to resolve this, apart from setting up the VM again from scratch, PLEASE share it with me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this VM a Windows 2008 R2 or Windows 2012 machine?

Comment: 2012 version it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated a Windows 2008 R2 VM with the same optional update and I can access it after reboot.

Try to reboot your VM machine again and see if you can get your access back. If did not work, then you will need to snapshot the VM's boot disk (for backup purpose if something goes wrong), delete the VM machine but keep its disks. Attach the boot disk to a test Windows VM machine as an additional disk and replace `D:\windows\system32\drivers\netkvm.sys` file with an older version file from test machine (I assumed `D:` will be drive name of the attached disk).

Detach the disk and create your Windows VM again using the repaired boot disk.

Comment: This worked! You are awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

My name is Yan Vugenfirer and I am the maintainer of [virtio-win](https://github.com/YanVugenfirer/kvm-guest-drivers-windows) drivers. I am trying to investigate how the issue that you are reporting happened (we shouldn't have drivers in Windows Update to begin with).

Could you please send me the version of the drivers from the following places:
1. Through device manager.
2. Right click on netkvm.sys and check the version info.

Thank you very much, your help is highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Yan.

Comment: Hello Yan. Under device manager and at the properties of the virtual adapter it displays 29/06/2014 as driver's date and unknown as driver's version.

Comment: If I check the properties of the file, the product version displayed is 40.1084.101.58000. Note that if I go to Windows updates, the update is at optional list. Hope you will be able to resolve the issue as to help others that may have the same problem. I lost a productive day trying to fix the issue using work arounds.